# Capturar a clausula WHERE de uma consulta SQL

Tags: python, regex

Preciso capturar somente a clausula `where` de várias consultas para analisar os filtros utilizados.
Por exemplo:

```
select "DIM_1"."col1",
"DIM_2"."col2" ,
"DIM_3"."col3" , 
"DIM_4"."col4" , 
"FAT_1"."col5"     
from "FAT_1",
 "DIM_1",
 "DIM_2",
 "DIM_3",
 "DIM_4"
where  "DIM_1"."col1" IS NOT NULL 
AND "DIM_2"."col2" LIKE ('SUCCESS')
AND "DIM_3"."col3" BETWEEN 20161213 AND 20161222
AND "DIM_4"."col4" > 0
```

Criei uma lista com o SQL, e em seguida tentei aplicar expressões regulares para extrair a parte do where, mas sem sucesso, segue abaixo o que tentei:

```
`for line in sql:`
    `if re.search(r'[where]\W',line):`
        `where.append(line)`
```

Infelizmente não consegui extrair somente a parte do where, sabem me dizer qual o erro que cometi e como consertar?

Comment: Segue um regex que retorna a clausula where: `(?:WHERE\s|ORDER BY\s|GROUP BY\s|\Z)(.*)`. Para ele funcionar, o comando precisa estar todo em uma linha. Vê se isso te ajuda

Comment: Regex para pegar a clausula where quando o comando sql estiver identado: `(?:WHERE\s|ORDER BY\s|GROUP BY\s|\Z)([^\n]*\n+)+(.*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que, o que você deseja é obter as clausulas do `where`.

Primeiramente vamos verificar o que pode vir apos o comando `where`.

#### Comandos pos-seguintes do `where`

[Segundo postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html).
Vendo só os mais comuns

- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT
- OFFSET
- "NADA" - Pois pode ser só o `where` sem nenhum comando posterior.

#### REGEX

- pattern : `(?<=where)(.*?)((ORDER BY|GROUP BY|HAVING|LIMIT|OFFSET|$).*)`
- flags : `si`

#### Explicação

- `(?<=where)` - garante que o que estamos pesquisando vem após `where`
- `(.*?)` - tudo que vier a seguir serão as clausulas.
- `((ORDER BY|GROUP BY|HAVING|LIMIT|OFFSET|$).*)` - garante que vai terminar em um dos comandos ou no fim(`$`).
- Flag : `s` - diz que o `.`(dot) deve incluir `\n` na pesquisa.
- Flag : `i` - case-insensitive - permite pesquisar maiúscula ou minuscula.

#### Exemplos

- [GROUP BY](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/1)
- [HAVING](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/2)
- [ORDER BY](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/3)
- [LIMIT](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/4)
- [OFFSET](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/5)
- ["NADA"](https://regex101.com/r/lSeY5P/6)

Answer (score 0):

Não manjo de Python, não sei como faz direito para atribuir um `select` para uma variável por conta das aspas, mas segue um exemplo que achei na documentação aplicado ao seu caso.

Conforme seu caso, acredito que não esta funcionando por estar verificando linha a linha, ou seja, ira encontrar o `where` na linha do `where`, porem nas próximas não irão.

Agora se pegar o grupo que corresponde a expressão regular, ai acredito que funcione.

```
   import re

    text = 'select "DIM_1"."col1",
    "DIM_2"."col2" ,
    "DIM_3"."col3" , 
    "DIM_4"."col4" , 
    "FAT_1"."col5"     
    from "FAT_1",
     "DIM_1",
     "DIM_2",
     "DIM_3",
     "DIM_4"
    where  "DIM_1"."col1" IS NOT NULL 
    AND "DIM_2"."col2" LIKE ('SUCCESS')
    AND "DIM_3"."col3" BETWEEN 20161213 AND 20161222
    AND "DIM_4"."col4" > 0'

    m = re.search('where.*', text)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
```

Caso alguém queira editar para correção do código, ou se não fizer
sentido, comente que deleto a resposta.

Fonte: [7.2. re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Valeu David, vou tentar. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
select = 'select * from tabela where campo = 1 and and campo2 = 2'
print (select[select.find('where'):])  # com o where incluso
```

ou

```
 print (select[select.find('where') + 5:]) # ou para excluir a palavra where
```